# How can I secure put login, password and other sensitive data in app bundle?

Tags: ios, objective-c, macos, security

My application needs to connect to a certain service. Login and password are used for this connection. This credentials must be secured.

Also my app needs to show some html-instructions with pictures. This data must be copy-protected.

I understand that I can't put these files/strings in app bundle in plain form.

But I also understand that if, for example, I put them in an encrypted archive, the hacker can still find the password string in the application executable.

Now I'm using an "implicit" password for my archive (something like `password = md5 ("qwerty")`). Is there enough protection or there are better ways? After all string with password can still be found, not in executable, but in RAM...

Comment: how about store them in keychain?

Comment: @Tj3n I need to secure static app data, not login and passwords that app users will enter

Comment: Use another API to get the secure info, or get the encrypt password, that way should be safe enough

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand. My app must connect to server. Server API uses login and password auth. There is no separate login and pass for different users. There is only one login and pass. I must store it somewhere in app bundle (may be I need to change it sometimes and i don't want to recompile app for that)

Comment: Thats why u can tell ur server to create another API or you have to create to get that login and password securely, also u can change it without recompile your app, if you put it in the bundle, can only either hardcode password or use API to get the password, which is similar to the above